# Is this a physics bug with WheelCollider or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am trying to create a drivable car model using Unity's WheelColliders and I have set up my CarControl.cs script like this: https://gist.github.com/victorbstan/e5903829576eaf6ce5e3

I am encountering two problems:

1. The car slightly turns without any steering being applied on a completely flat surface.
2. The vehicle accelerates and decelerates inconsistently given the torque applied to it.

To get a better idea of what I mean, I made a video recording of the setup and play-through:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuMT_AzRHbA&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without really digging into it, my initial impression is that your WheelCollider friction values are probably too low. Increasing the forward friction will probably help with your inconsistent acceleration and the sideways friction will probably address your steering issue.

Comment: Unity 5 has upgraded their PhysX engine and admit to have had bugs in their previous implementation... Since version 5, I have been able to get decent simulation without these problems. Perhaps you are right, though it's irrelevant for me check at this point. Thanks for the suggestions though.